# Checking some domains takes a very long time with DNSJava

Tags: java, dnsjava

I have noticed that when checking some domains using the DNSJava library it take a very long time to get dns records.

This is the code I am using

```
   private void dnsCheck(DomainName domainName) {
        try {
            final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Record[] recordsA = new Lookup(domainName.getDomainName(), Type.A).run();
            Record[] recordsAAAA = new Lookup(domainName.getDomainName(), Type.AAAA).run();
            Record[] recordsCNAME = new Lookup(domainName.getDomainName(), Type.CNAME).run();
            Record[] recordsMX = new Lookup(domainName.getDomainName(), Type.MX).run();
            Record[] recordsNS = new Lookup(domainName.getDomainName(), Type.NS).run();
            Record[] recordsPTR = new Lookup(domainName.getDomainName(), Type.PTR).run();
            Record[] recordsSRV = new Lookup(domainName.getDomainName(), Type.SRV).run();
            Record[] recordsSOA = new Lookup(domainName.getDomainName(), Type.SOA).run();
            Record[] recordsTXT = new Lookup(domainName.getDomainName(), Type.TXT).run();
            Record[] recordsCAA = new Lookup(domainName.getDomainName(), Type.CAA).run();
            Record[] recordsDS = new Lookup(domainName.getDomainName(), Type.DS).run();
            Record[] recordsDNSKEY = new Lookup(domainName.getDomainName(), Type.DNSKEY).run();
            final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println("Total execution time for domain: " + domainName.getDomainName() + " " + (endTime - startTime));
      ....
      ....
       } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The domain names below take a very long time to return results

```
webdddd.com 66042 milliseconds
gotest.com 16114 milliseconds
testblog.com 27575 milliseconds
testapp.com 66283 milliseconds
```

But the following come back fast

```
prodddd.com 115 milliseconds
ddddmedia.com 179 milliseconds
greendddd.com 598 milliseconds
ddddbox.com 619 milliseconds
```

Am I not using DNSJava correctly? Is there anything I can do to get the results faster?